# How to format Google Polymer files in django using Bower?

Tags: django, polymer, bower

I am trying to learn to use Google Polymer and wanted to use Django as I have some data crunching planned for the app and wanted to use python for it. The google Polymer website ([Getting the code](https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/start/getting-the-code.html)) highly suggested installing Polymer through bower. I went to the [bower website](http://bower.io/) and they said to install bower using nmp. I installed nmp (nodejs.org, I ran out of link privileges), installed bower and proceeded to install Polymer into my django virtual environment. I found a functioning website with it's files on Github (github.com/mc706/three_most_important_things) and compared their settings.py files to mine, and their directory hierarchy to see how they had implemented Polymer. It appears that they didn't use bower to install polymer, and they have polymer as an app inside their django project. I am not a django expert but I have used Bootstrap with it and had no problem. I assumed Polymer was just a set of css and js files that made code implementation easier. I have tried shifting the Polymer "components" around (first in bower-components, then static/components) and changed my link references to point there, but I still get a blank page when I render it. Can someone give me a simple file hierarchy example of where the polymer files should be stored and how to reference them? eg.

```
project
  bin
  include
  lib
  project
    project main
    project apps
  static
    static
      components
```

There are only a view sites that mention django+polymer together, and normally it's a question about {{}} and {% verbatim %} usage. I can't seem to get to that point. Any setup advice would greatly appreciated.

Comment: when you get a blank page, are there any errors in the browser console?

Comment: @akonsu , I don't get any errors anymore (I had misspelled some settings but ironed them out) when I serve the page. I added text to the page to make sure I was able to see any changes made to the file (base.html). I created a polymer element "driller" in driller.html, and imported it to base.html, but that's when nothing shows up. I'm pretty sure I'm using the correct format for serving the polymer elements from driller.html but I have a feeling that I'm not referencing them correctly somewhere in my django settings.